# How to obtain Bundle ID for an IOS App when I have a '.ipa' file for the app installed on my iPAD

Tags: ios, appium, bundle-identifier

I am trying to automate a test on my ipad which has my app installed on it. I am using Appium for automating the app. It's asking me to enter a bundle ID of the App that needs to be tested.

Could some help me find a way to find the bundle ID for the app from either the app installed on my IPAD or from the .ipa file downloaded on my iMAC?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the bundle Identifier by opening the .ipa file using Archive Utility on your mac.
Once you open the ipa with Archive Utility. You see app directory.

Then go to Payload -> App file(your appname)( Right click to show package contents)-> open Info.plist-> Look for Bundle Identifier value.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [BundleidHelper](https://github.com/if1else0/bundleid_helper) gem:

1. Install gem

   ```
   gem install bundleid_helper
   ```
2. Use this gem to get bundle id

   ```
   bundleid name.ipa
   ```

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

was referring to another website for the same. Reposting the answer from the other website

1. Copy the .ipa file and rename the extension to .zip. (So e.g. Pages.ipa will become Pages.zip)
2. Unzip the zip file. You will get a new folder named like the zip file.
3. Search for the file iTunesMetadata.plist in that new folder.
4. Open the file with a text editor and search for softwareVersionBundleId. For Pages this looks like this and is com.apple.Pages: